# Issue with Python sockets between client and server

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I am getting a headache from trying to figure out where the problem is. I have a basic client and a server, the client sends a request and the server replies with an answer, the problem is, that the server does not send what is expected from him.

I would really appreciate anyone that can help me, thank you very much.
Here is the code:
client code:

```py
def main():
    import socket
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',8000))
    info = input(r"Enter what you want to send to the server: ")
    while info != "exit":
        my_socket.send(info.encode('ascii'))
        if info != "EXIT":
            data_from_server = my_socket.recv(2).decode('ascii')
            data_from_server = my_socket.recv(int(data_from_server))
            print(data_from_server.decode('ascii'))
            info = input("Enter what you want to send to the server: ")
        else:
            info = "exit"
    my_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the server code:

```py
import socket
import sys
import time
from random import randrange
SERVER_NAME = "010101"

def number_of_elements(str):
    num = 0
    for e in str:
        num += 1
    return num


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8000))
    while True:
        server_socket.listen(1)
        client_socket, client_adresss = server_socket.accept()
        client_request = client_socket.recv(4)
        while client_request != b'EXIT':
            if client_request == b'TIME':
                num_of_chars = number_of_elements(time.ctime())
                client_socket.send(str(num_of_chars).encode('ascii'))
                client_socket.send(time.ctime().encode('ascii'))
            elif client_request == b'NAME':
                num_of_chars = number_of_elements(SERVER_NAME)
                client_socket.send(str(num_of_chars).encode('ascii'))
                client_socket.send(SERVER_NAME.encode('ascii'))
            elif client_request == b'RAND':
                num = 2
                client_socket.send(str(num).encode('ascii'))
                random_num = randrange(11)
                client_socket.send(str(random_num).encode('ascii'))
            else:
                s = str(len("Incorrect Command"))
                client_socket.send(s.encode('ascii'))
                client_socket.send(b"Incorrect Command")
            try:    
                client_request = client_socket.recv(4)
            except:
                client_request = b"EXIT"
        client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()





if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Here's an example
[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work well" ?  Does it not connect reliably?  Or does it have another issue after the connection?

Comment: It does connect, the problem is with the requesting, I've added a photo as an example. When the client request 'TIME' the server, first sends how many bytes the answer has, and then he should send the time, however it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This call:

```
client_request = client_socket.recv(4)
```

Means you are asking for 4 bytes.  But the socket library can, **and will** deliver less than that based on the behavior of TCP.  And your code is not checking the number of bytes actually received.

Code your server as if it was only going to receive 1 byte at a time. And/or be prepared to invoke `recv` multiple times and to accumulate the number of bytes into a sequential buffer until the expected number has been received.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I wrote this call beacuse the client and the server work on protocol that I invented, which means that the client should only send this options : TIME, RAND, NAME, EXIT. which all have 4 bytes. if the client sends more than 4 bytes i do not treat them, only the first four.

Comment: **But that's not how TCP works.**  TCP is a streaming protocol, not a message protocol.  IP fragmentation, TCP segmentation, and burps on the Internet can cause your application defined "message" to be broken up into different packets.  And if the socket layer has only received a partial of the bytes originally sent, it will happily return what it has to the caller - even if the caller requested more bytes than actually received.  Do this, type `telnet 127.0.0.1 8000` and try to type `NAME` into the terminal window.  Your server will only received one char at a time.

Comment: At the very least, change your code to use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag (if available on your platform).

Comment: Hi, I've changed my server to recieve only one byte at a time, as you said. However, after I send the second request to the server, the client get stuck. Here is what I added: 
while True:
      data = client_socket.recv(1)
       client_request += data
        if not data: 
                break                     
But I think it does not get out of the while loop, I've added it in the try section.